# CSS:a gift on a rating bar

Tags: html, css, gif, ratingbar

I want to put this : 
http://livepipe.net/control/rating A rating bar CSS and my only problem is the image.gif. Can anyone help me with that? that if I try to build it happen that I gif animations:  circles that change in a time interval and not when you click on them. If anyone can upload an example or explain how to build this type of gif correctly greatly appreciate it.

http://livepipe.net/control/rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of that webpage, you'll see that [this is the image](http://livepipe.net/stylesheets/rating.gif) used for the rating.

It is a single .gif and it is not animated. To control what selection to show, he has defined a number of CSS classes as follows:

```
.rating_container a {  
    float:left;  
    display:block;  
    width:25px;  
    height:25px;  
    border:0;  
    background-image:url("/stylesheets/rating.gif");  
} 

.rating_container a.rating_off {  
    background-position:0 0px;  
} 

.rating_container a.rating_half {  
    background-position:0 -25px;  
} 

.rating_container a.rating_on {  
     background-position:0 -50px;  
 } 

.rating_container a.rating_selected {  
     background-position:0 -75px;  
}
```

Every `<a>` tag within an element with the class `rating_container` will automatically set that entire rating sheet as it's background image. As the width/height is forced to be 25 by 25, it will only show a small section of it. He then sets the `<a>` classes individually based on the rating. For example when a rating is set on, it becomes `<a class='rating_on'>`, the matching CSS changes the images background-position by -50px on the y axis, this causes the 25x25 `<a>` window to show a different picture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need one image but multiple images:

- rating_off
- rating_half
- rating_on
- rating_selected

You then show 5 times rating_off when nothing is selected
2 times rating_on and 3 times rating_off when 2 is selected ...
rating_half is used when you not fully select an option...

The rating_selected is used when a user hovers over the rating (before he selects)

**You don't need any animated gifs**